# Book recommendations for Hermitian geometry

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I have just started my PhD thesis on geometry and I work in a Hermitian context.  I know the basic definitions like Hermitian and Kaehlerian manifolds, complex space forms and slant submanifolds (i did my master's thesis about it). So i would like to know about any book which could use like manual. A book where i could find any defintion and a substantial amount of results (I dont want a basic book whichcant  expand my knowledge).

Any ideas?? Thanks for advance

Comment: I don't think people actually got round to writing a comprehensive book on Hermitian manifolds yet.  But really, what sort of things are you looking for?  A more analysis-ish type (PDEs, Sobolev spaces, estimates, ...), geometry type (e.g., harmonic morphisms, twistor fheory, ...) or something else (curvature flow? general Riemannian geometry? something to sit on the shelf?)

Comment: Something else like Riemann geometry, the study of its invariants or any interesting special cases, curvature flow as you say

Comment: I don't know if anyone has written a book about Hermitian geometry. Maybe Kobayashi's "Hyperbolic complex spaces" talks about it, or Kobayashi-Nomizu's "Foundations of differential geometry". There are some research papers that discuss Hermitian geometry, like https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/identite_KN.pdf or https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/theses/schweitzer_bott_chern_2007.pdf for example, but I don't know of introductory articles or book about it.

Comment: Fangyang Zheng's book _Complex differential geometry_ has some good material concerning Hermitian geometry. These articles are also worth reading: https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2481 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0207 Anything by Gauduchon is also great!